# How to get the flv file from a youtube page

Tags: python, youtube

How would you get the "flv" file from A youtube page for example:www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8YCSJpF4g4... Any ideas?

So far ive tried:

```
import urllib
import os
import sys

page=urllib.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuLDIgfPae8')
result = page.read()
#result=open("test.html").read()
print result
startindex = result.index("var swfArgs")
result = result[startindex:]
endindex=result.index("};")
result=result[:endindex]
result =  result.split(",")
get={}
print result
def download(url,output):
    """Copy the contents of a file from a given URL to a local file."""   
    webFile = urllib.urlretrieve(url,output+".flv")

for line in result:
    if "video_id" in line or "\"t\"" in line :
        v,vnum = line.replace("\"","").split(":")
        get[v.strip()]=vnum.strip()

dload = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=%s&t=%s" % ( get['video_id'],get['t'])

try :
    download(dload,get['video_id'])
except Exception,e:
    print "Error: ",e
```

but this gives me an error:

```
startindex = result.index("var swfArgs")
ValueError: substring not found
```

and im not sure how to fix this error.

@icktoofay

how would i recreat all of these requests?:

[image]

Please help this is killing me.

Comment: This question should be migrated to webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: @haimg: I believe WebApps is for users of web applications, not people trying to write programs to interact with them.

Comment: I know one way to do it, but I think you need to put more effort into your question before I'm going to help you.

Comment: @P'sao: I'm sorry I mised the "python" tag on your question. Without it, it just looks like you want to download something from youtube. Indeed, please provide more details.

Comment: I just edited it :) im not sure what other detailed i could provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to take a look at [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/). This is a short description taken from its website:

> **youtube-dl** is a small command-line program to download videos from
>   YouTube.com and a few more sites. It requires the **Python** interpreter,
>   version 2.x (x being at least 5), and it is not platform specific. It
>   should work in your Unix box, in Windows or in Mac OS X. It is
>   released to the public domain, which means you can modify it,
>   redistribute it or use it however you like.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your current code is that indeed, `var swfArgs` does not appear in the source of that web page. YouTube is constantly changing their pages, so I'm going to tell you how to find what you'll need to do, rather than what YouTube currently does.

Open the page in a browser with good debugging tools. For example, Firefox with Firebug or Chrome with its developer tools. Open the developer tools and go to the network tab or whatever your tools call it.

Chrome's developer tools network tab:
[image: Chrome developer tools network tab]

Firebug's developer tools network tab:
[image: Firebug network tab]

Find the FLV. Find parameters in the URL and other related locations. See if any of that data is on the web page. Also see if any of that data is from other requests, which may have parameters which are on the web page.

Simply recreate the requests in Python, and you'll get the FLV, just as YouTube's official site gets it.