# How to get the direct links to video file using youtube API

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

How to get the direct links (on FLV, MP4, WebM, 3GP files)

to video file on youtube using the Youtube API.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube API does not offer the feature you are looking for. Btw you can use for example Python/PHP to do that. Here are a couple of links (maybe they are outdated but you can get the big picture):

http://ifthikhan.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/getting-url-for-flv-of-a-youtube-video-in-php/

[youtube get_video not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602956/youtube-get-video-not-working)

[How to get the flv file from a youtube page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694213/how-to-get-the-flv-file-from-a-youtube-page)